# Gridview with row being edited causing error when form submitted

Tags: asp.net

Using ASP.NET VB, I have a form with some text boxes and a Gridview.  If a user clicks the Edit button on a row in the gridview, and then tries to submit the form with a row still in edit mode on the Gridview, this error is generated -

"Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation. "

Any idea how to prevent this error??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just go to web.config and make it false.

i also face that error and i fixed it by doing this.

check these link as reference

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/ShowMessages.aspx?ThreadID=35528
http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/155642-Invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-Wants-event-validation-enabled/

check my answer if you get your answer and vote it.thanx